# sendmail using daemon@localhost

Tags: sendmail

I have a server that hosts 7 websites. They all feature the ability to email to the user from programs running on the server (such as forgotten passwords, notifications, etc.). They will have a reply address such as DO-NOT-REPLY@somedomain.com. In the header reply-to address is DAEMON@localdomain.localhost. This causes some receiving mail servers to reject the mail because the sending email addresses do not match (I believe it is a 553 error).

Most of what I have googled says to use the generics table. However, this seems to require the user to actually be an account on the system (Linux). For example:

```
bob robert.e.user@someotherdomain.com
```

In my case, I have a number of "users" named DO-NOT-REPLY but in different domains. How would I specify them? Where would I specify them?

I'm very confused right now.

Comment: add the domains to your authoritative domains list in `sendmail.cw`. That'll let one single DO-NOT-REPLY system account be legitimate for all those domains.

Comment: @MarcB That is the way I am configured. The domains are all listed and sendmail has been restarted.

Comment: What do you use to serve the websites? [ Web server (apache?), scripting extension (php?)]

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Running on Apache with php as the scripting language.

Answer (score 0):

**SENDING (at Unix PHP)**

mail function in php can set:

- header sender ("From:" header)
  [optional additional_headers parameter]
- envelope sender to receive bounces ("MAIL FROM:" at SMTP level) 
  [passing `-f addreess` to MTA via optional additional_parameters parameter]

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Limiting it may be tricky (e.g. forcing each web site to use sender addresses in its own domain)

**RECEIVING (BOUNCES)**

You may use `FEATURE(virtusertable)` in sendmail configuration.